# Is DataFX Replaced by Gluon Connect

Tags: javafx-8

I would like to use `DataFX` to a new javafx client project which will consume web service request by http and i thought `DataFX` would be perfect.

The problem is when i try to go to `http://javafxdata.org/` or `http://datafx.io/` both redirect to `http://gluonhq.com/labs/connect/`.

Anyone aware that `DataFX` is replaced by `Gluon Connect`, or know a better JavaFX library to utilise web services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else stumbling upon this question, the following is from the [Gluon website](http://gluonhq.com/labs/):

> Gluon Connect is the next generation data sync library, carrying on
>   the work initially done as part of DataFX (which was developed by
>   Gluon developers too).